# Selenium webdriver just stop working for Firefox browser with GeckoDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My Java selenium TestNG script correctly work with google chrome browser. But when I try with Firefox and GeckoDriver some test runs are got failed and following error displayed. Please be kind enough to suggest me any solution.

```
Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\Naveen\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath

[Parent 4944, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
```

Comment: you need to show the full error which will reveal the cause

Comment: what is your selenium version? Please use the supported version of geckodriver with the selenium version.

Comment: Please post the code snippet for which you are getting this error.

Comment: Please check the my code snippet. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing says it all :

- **`Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath`** :     When `GeckoDriver` initiates a new `Firefox Browsing Session` **openvrpaths.vrpath** is accessed to resolve Browser internal calls. This is a common issue when your system contains OS chores and are **harmless**. To get around this error you have to run `CCleaner` tool before and after your `Test Execution` which will clean up the OS chores.
- **`[Parent 4944, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346`** : It is typical `pipe error` which is common while initializing a new `Firefox Browsing Session` and accessing the **chrome**. These errors are also **harmless**.
- Here is a typical example where **GeckoDriver** successfully connects to the **Marionette** even after facing those errors :

  ```
  1503490593860   Marionette  DEBUG   Received observer notification "domwindowclosed"
  Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\AtechM_03\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath
  [GPU 6544] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w64-00000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
  Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\AtechM_03\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath
  [Child 5480] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w64-00000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
  [Child 5480] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w64-00000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
  1503490594683   Marionette  DEBUG   Setting recommended pref toolkit.cosmeticAnimations.enabled to false
  1503490594684   Marionette  DEBUG   Setting recommended pref datareporting.policy.dataSubmissionPolicyAccepted to false
  1503490594685   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 57904
  1503490594703   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 57904
  1503490594749   geckodriver::marionette DEBUG   Connected to Marionette on localhost:57904
  ```
- If your **`Firefox`** browser stops working the reason is something else but not the above mentioned logs.